# Apply scaling to rigged model without affecting visual aspect

Tags: rigging, armature, transforms

I rigged my model and I realized that it has a scale of -1 on X axis (left/right).
Then if I mirror the model the left bones deform the right and vice versa, I tried "Mirror vertex groups" but it does strange things (seems a buggy function). I though about applying a inverse scaling to the vertices and the scaling the the object but it doesn't work. I don't know how to do.
Is there a script or something to do so ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the armature selected in object mode, apply the scale - <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> ->Apply Scale.

Then in edit mode select the all bones, ensure there aren't hidden bones on other layers, and scale -1 on the x axis - <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>

Now in pose mode the bones should effect the correct side.

Comment: Didn't think about that way,  thanks sambler !

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>>*Apply Scale* will set all scale values to one. This will fix that issue, but be careful it could mess up scale animation and anything depended on the scale (save your file before trying it).

Comment: In fact this is my problem as NEED to apply the scale to my model BUT it deform everything if I do...

Comment: So you tried it, it didn't say in your question...

Comment: Yes sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to scale models without messing up your whole rig. Just scale the world in metric system.